# Unable to get the first two items in an array when creating a Fibonacci sequence in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement, fibonacci

I've been trying to create a Fibonacci sequence that always starts with [0, 1] using simple JS. However, the way it's written now, the function does not return the first two items in an array when I call the corresponding n number. So, for n = 1 and n = 2 (and ONLY those values of n), I get undefined when calling the function. However, whenever I call n larger than 2, the Fibonacci sequence returns correctly, with the correct amount of array items (so, including items 0 and 1, which I am unable to call on their own).

Here is the code:

```
function generator(n) {
var output = [];
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 1;
var next;

if (n === 1) {
    output = [0];
} else if (n === 2) {
    output = [0, 1];
} else {
    output = [num1, num2];
    for (var count = 2; count < n; count++) {
    next = num1 + num2;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = next;
    output.push(next); 
}

return output;




}

}
```

Would anyone know what is wrong in the code? Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: You're missing a close brace for the for loop in the third case. Which might mean the first two cases don't actually hit the return statement, because the return statment is now in the 'else' case only. (or that might just be a typo in your question)

Comment: If you would force yourself to always properly indent your code, you would avoid such mistakes. And your edit confirms Rup's remark.

Comment: Omg, you are incredible, thanks! It was really only the incorrect placement of the return statement! You won't believe how long I've spent figuring this out. Thanks again!

Comment: @mrcrazyog .. as a practice, ALWAYS indent your code properly.

Comment: @HymnZzy yup, my bad. A stupid beginner's mistake. Hope I'll remember it now. Thanks again :)

Comment: https://beautifier.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is a problem with brackets in the code you have posted above. the code should look like this.

```
function generator(n) {
var output = [];
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 1;
var next;

if (n === 1) {
    output = [0];
} else if (n === 2) {
    output = [0, 1];
} else {
    output = [num1, num2];
    for (var count = 2; count < n; count++) {
    next = num1 + num2;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = next;
    output.push(next); 
}}

return output;
}
```

However, this may be just a typo issue. And secondly, if I use the corrected type of the function, there is no problem.

```js
function generator(n) {
var output = [];
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 1;
var next;

if (n === 1) {
    output = [0];
} else if (n === 2) {
    output = [0, 1];
} else {
    output = [num1, num2];
    for (var count = 2; count < n; count++) {
    next = num1 + num2;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = next;
    output.push(next); 
}}

return output;
}

//testing
for(let i=1;i<=5;i++){
  console.log(`${i}'th result`)
  console.log(generator(i));
}
```

Try this one, it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks so much! It does work! As you guys have said, it was a problem with my stupid indentation and an incorrect placement of the return. I have to pay more attention to it.

Comment: You are welcome! My advice, use some kind of IDEA, editor, whatever it is that you can find helpful/joyful. Good luck!